# What signature should a windowed c++-winrt main() method have?

Tags: c++-winrt

I have Windowed a c++-winrt app with a main() that looks like this:

```
int main() {
    Application::Start([](const ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams&) {
        new CWindowsPlatformApp();
    });
}
```

CWindowsPlatformApp inhertis from winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationT. However when compiling I get a linker error like this:

```
vccorlibd.lib(climain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "?main@@YAHP$01$AAV?$Array@P$AAVString@Platform@@$00@Platform@@@Z" (?main@@YAHP$01$AAV?$Array@P$AAVString@Platform@@$00@Platform@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl _main(void)" (?_main@@YAHXZ)
```

The CX-signature of main does still work but I am converting all CX-code to c++-winrt currently.

```
int __cdecl main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^)
```

If I change the subsystem to a console app it does link correctly as well.

But is there anyway I can specify a windows app-main() with c++-winrt?

Answer (score 4):

The traditional entry point function for a graphical Windows application is [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
}
```

Here's a [complete example using C++/WinRT](https://github.com/kennykerr/cppwinrt/blob/737cbbb11fe56e4d94ff9d84a44aa72e0689016b/Store/Blocks/App.cpp).

Comment: I have a number of templates including C++/WinRT available on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) that you might find useful to reference.

Answer (score 4):

If you crack open your vcxproj file, you'll see this property assignment:

```
<AppContainerApplication>true</AppContainerApplication>
```

AppContainerApplication is not a well-named property, since it combines app containment with language selection (C++/CX).  It enables both the /ZW (C++/CX) compiler switch, and causes the linker to use the C++/CX CRT library, vccorlib(d).lib, which defines the app's entry point and in turn causes your link error.

As you migrate to a native project, you'll need to disable both of these features.  You could try to do that incrementally within your project.  But the simplest isolation is at the project boundary.  For example, you can't compile a single pch that's #includable by both ISO C++ and C++/CX source files.  I'd suggest moving all your C++/CX code into a static library with its own pch and AppContainerApplication=true, and link this into your main app project with native main() and AppContainerApplication=false.